# closing the aspx page by writing code?

Tags: asp.net

In my web application, wheni click on GO button one new window will open [it is a page (.aspx page)]. in that new window when i click on submit button, the new window will close.
please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript to call document.window.close() on the click event. You would need to post code or more details about your platform to provide any more.

Comment: @@schroedingers thank you for response i write the Client script code. it is closing the window but it is asking confirmation but i dont want it. i wnat to close window directly my code is like this.... ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Button1, GetType(), "sas", "<script> window.close();</script>",false );

Comment: Closing without confirmation is "not possible for good reason". You might like to look at this post for more : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629801/javascript-to-close-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-firefox-without-confirmation-box

Comment: possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375406/programmatically-close-aspx-page-from-code-behind