# How to Close Window at onload event of body at IE 8 and IE 7?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I use this code `window.onload=function Print(){window.open(); window.close()}` at YouPrint.aspx. It working fine at IE 9 but it does not work in IE 8 and IE 7. It shows a JavaScript error like this "Stack Flow error". Why? If you have solution, please show me the way to solve this problem. Please Help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript to close IE6, IE7, IE8 and Firefox without confirmation box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629801/javascript-to-close-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-firefox-without-confirmation-box)

Answer (score 0):

Works ok for me in IE7 / IE8 using the following test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<body onload="window.print(); window.close();">

    <span>Test</span>

</body>
</html>
```

What doc type are you using? I've tested it with strict and that works too.
More info please...